# Change provide service value to test different cases

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking

I'm testing a modal behaviour where depending of user actions, the result of modal can return several options.

The code based is as follows:

```
const modalInstance = this.$uibModal.open({
      animation: true,
      resolve: {},
      component: 'modalView',
      size: 'lg'
    });
    let dismissed = false;
    modalInstance.result.then((result) => {
      if (result.redirect) { 
        this.redirectToBrowseIfReverted();
      } else {
        this.redirectToSaveTarget();
      }
    },
    () => {
      dismissed = true;
    });
```

So depending of redirect is true or false, it'll call `redirectToBrowseIfReverted` or `redirectToSaveTarget`. To start testing this out I just inject `module`through `angular.mock.module` and passing `$uibModal` service to `$provide` to mock as desired:

```
let mockModal = () => ({
  open: () => {
    return { result: $q.resolve({ redirect: true }) };
 }
});

beforeEach(() => {
 angular.mock.module(moduleName, $provide => {
 $provide.service('$uibModal', mockModal);
});
```

This certainly will return `redirect` value as `true` and call `redirectToBrowseIfReverted` but I want to test the case when this is `false`but I don't know how to tell angular in a particular UT case to override the `$provide` service for `$uibModal` and return `false` instead. Any help will be really much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you didn't mention what test framework you're working with.

If it's Jasmine, you can utilise a spy (see https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies) to dynamically change the returned value.

You would have to inject the service into your test like so:

```
var $uibModal;
var $q

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$uibModal_, _$q_) {
  $uibModal = _$uibModal_;
  $q = _$q_;
}));
```

Then you can use spies inside the tests themselves:

```
it('should return redirect as true', function() {
  spyOn($uibModal, 'open').and.returnValue({
    result: $q.resolve({ redirect: true })
  });
  <the rest of your test>
});

it('should return redirect as false', function() {
  spyOn($uibModal, 'open').and.returnValue({
    result: $q.resolve({ redirect: false })
  });
  <the rest of your test>
});
```

Apologies for not es6ing it, but hopefully you get the jist. :)

edit: Also if you have a lot of tests and you're concerned about putting a spy in every test, you can do something like this to test the failure case only once:

```
var $uibModal;
var $q;
var modalSpy;

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$uibModal_, _$q_) {
  $uibModal = _$uibModal_;
  $q = _$q_;
  modalSpy = spyOn($uibModal, 'open').and.returnValue({
    result: $q.resolve({ redirect: true })
  });
}));

it('returns false for this one test only', function() {
  modalSpy.and.returnValue({
    result: $q.resolve({ redirect: false })
  });
});
```

As a spy can only ever have a single execution strategy, it takes the last one. It's a bit hacky, but it works.

Comment: Thanks mate! I was using `spyOn` but in bad way, I was spying on the service rather than the `scope` of the controller:

`spyOn($uibModal, 'open').and.returnValue({ result: $q.resolve({ redirect: false }) });` rather than `spyOn(controller.$uibModal, 'open').and.returnValue({ result: $q.resolve({ redirect: false }) });`

After all I was setting the modal service on the constructor to make available on the controller scope:

`constructor($uibModal, $rootScope, $scope, $timeout, $q) {
    this.$uibModal = $uibModal;

...`

Thanks for the solution!